# Property 'data' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IProps'. ts(2322)

Tags: typescript, next.js

I got the following error:

> Type '{ data: never; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IProps'.Property 'data' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IProps'.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { InfoQuiz } from './InfoQuiz';

interface IProps {
  id: string; // Define the prop type for 'id'
}

export default function UserQuizData({ id }: IProps) {
  const { user } = useUser();
  const [quizData, setQuizData] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (user) {
      const fetchUserQuizData = async () => {
        const response = await fetch(`/api/user-quiz-data?id=${id}`, {
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${user.publicMetadata.public_id}`,
          },
        });
        const data = await response.json();
        setQuizData(data);
      };

      fetchUserQuizData();
    }
  }, [user]);

  return <>{quizData && <InfoQuiz data={quizData} />}</>;
}
```

Could you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

The error occures at this line

```js
<InfoQuiz data={quizData} />
```

You are calling `InfoQuiz` component passing to it `data` as props but this `data` does not exist on type `'IntrinsicAttributes & IProps'`.

You have to make change there, something like this:

```js
interface InfoQuizProps {
  data: any; // Adjust the type accordingly based on your data structure
}
export function InfoQuiz({ data }: InfoQuizProps) {
  // ...
}
```